# Anyway to pass a preexisting JSON object to an OPTION in jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

What the title says.

I know I can do

```
<option data-value='{"name":"rajiv","age":"40"}'>a</option>
```

to manually pass through individual variables, but let's say I have a preexisting JSON, is there a way I can do something like

```
<option data-value='PrexistingJSON'>a</option>
```

In my code, I'm doing this on AJAX success (appending options to my select)

Here is the snippet:

```
.....

success: function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i) {
        $('#select').append($('<option data-value=\'' + result[i] + '\'></option>').val(result[i].ID)
        .html(result[i].LastName + ", " + result[i].FirstName);
});

.....
```

Where `result[i]` is my JSON object. I am getting `[object Object]` returned when I try to access it with `$('#assign_employee option:selected').data("value");`.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Try with + JSON.stringify(result[i]) +

Comment: @juvian Oh my, of course! I must have had some serious tunnel vision I can't believe I overlooked stringify. That got it working - thank you so much!

Comment: Happens :). Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to [@juvian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308055/juvian). I simply had to stringify my object. Here is the working code:

```
.....

success: function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i) {
        $('#select').append($('<option data-value=\'' + JSON.stringify(result[i]) + '\'></option>').val(result[i].ID)
        .html(result[i].LastName + ", " + result[i].FirstName);
});

.....
```

Comment: Now you understand the difference between JSON and Javascript objects, right?